# Send email from gmail as another email address from an owned domain name

Tags: email, gmail, domain, smtp

tl;dr; I would like to send emails using my domain extensions. I own some domains registered on Gandi, and I would like to send you an email using an email address using this domain extension.

Recently Gandi removed its free mailing service. From long ago, I have domains registered on Gandi + an email redirection to my Gmail address (in order to receive emails sent to something@mydomain.com) + a postmaster@mydomain.com email account on Gandi (allowing me to send emails using my domain extension) + eventually a "Send mail as" rule on Gmail that uses the SMTP server of Gandi postmaster account. With this, I can receive emails from all my domains on my Gmail account, and I can select from Gmail from which email (domain) I would like to send my email.

Unfortunately, since the Gandi migration, I cannot use the free postmaster account anymore. Thus I cannot send emails from Gmail with my domain emails.

What option do I have to send emails as before, if possible signed and without headers from my gmail account?

I was thinking about getting a VM, modifying the DNS entry on my domains, installing a postfix server and trying to find a good tutorial, but I've read this from DigitalOcean:

> As of June 22, 2022, DigitalOcean is blocking SMTP for all new accounts. As a part of this new policy, we have partnered with SendGrid so our customers can still send emails with ease.

Not sure what it means, and not sure how can I fix my issue.

Comment: @1NN I have edited my question. Tell me if it is more understandable.

Comment: Have you looked into any other VM hosts besides DigitalOcean?

Comment: @nowox **1)** Which part about SendGrid isn't clear? They're a service that allows you to send outgoing mail from a server (https://sendgrid.com/pricing/) **2)** You should be able to setup the Gmail Sand As using Google's own SMTP by using your Gmail credentials for the SMTP credentials

Comment: Gmail doesn't want me to use Google SMTP to send emails from another email address.

Comment: What settings did you use? Try following https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-use-free-google-smtp-server

Comment: @YisroelTech Not working. Seems Gmail doesn't like using smtp.gmail.com for other emails. It seems logical otherwise, anybody would be able to send email as elon.musk@tesla.com :(

Comment: For that purpose they send a verification email to the email address added. What exactly isn't working, at which step do you get stuck and what's the error?

Comment: Well it kind of work. I had to create an App Password on my Gmail Account. Then it works, but in two tests I've made. Sent emails goes into quarantine for "fishing". I suppose because it is sent through gmail smtp.

Comment: Your might simply need to add an SPF record to your domain indicating Google is a valid sender for your domain. See https://support.google.com/a/answer/10685031?sjid=11395888174887563582-NA

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this myself. I couldn't figure out how to get Gmail to log into Gandi's SMTP server (Gandi was denying all requests no matter which user/email I tried, even the admin@mydomain.com username that worked before). I even tried just giving Gandi the ridiculous $42/year they wanted for a paid mailbox, with no luck - Gmail still couldn't authenticate to send outgoing mail through them.

I finally solved it by transferring my domain to namecheap, which has a private email service thing, which along with the domain was a fraction of the price of Gandi. And Gmail SMTP was able to authenticate with it instantly. ‍♀️